# Bilinear forms by P B Battacharya, Linear Algebra, Chap 7
Example 7.1.10.(4)

Tags: multilinear-algebra, bilinear-form, symplectic-linear-algebra

Let B be a bilinear form on a vector space V over R whose matrix wrt basis (e1,e2) of V is 
((1,2),(2,-1)) row-wise.
Find a new basis of V wrt which the matrix of B is identity matrix.
How to proceed ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Can you tell us anything about $B(f_1, f_1)$, where $f_1$ is a potential first element of the new basis?

Comment: I realized that f1 is (1,0)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should seriously doubt the result you're trying to prove (i.e., that such a basis exists). For if $M$ and $N$ are the matrices of a bilinear form $B$ with respect to two different bases, then there's a matrix $Q$ with 
$$
N = Q^t M Q
$$
Since $\det Q^t = \det Q$, that means that the signs of the determinants of $M$ and $N$ are the same. The determinant of the identity matrix is $+1$.